# Immediately-invoked function expression with additional parameters at beginning

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

What is the purpose of the zero `(0, _child...)` in the following expression

```
var python = (0, _child_process.spawn)('python2.7', [dummy_arguments]);
```

I think this is an IIFE but I don't know what is the purpose of the zero as an additional argument.

Comment: Comma operator.

Comment: This is not an IIFE because there is no `function` expression.